# SOAP Web Service Single User Login Integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, soap, single-sign-on

Working on a project where i need to implement single-user login, or letting them use the same login on their main website, as well as on another site.  Right now they are using a SOAP web service.  I have used my googlefu to try and work this out, but I need some help.

https://www.kappaalphatheta.org/gateway2/production/com/theta/authentication/AuthenticationGateway.cfc?wsdl

Just above this is a link to their service.  I am using a .net authentication service on our website.  With no experience in SOAP or authentication, how can I set up my site to authenticate a user from their service, and also pull other information like address and email address?

I have looked at their site, and they are using javascript and not PHP, whereas on google most people use PHP.  I would prefer to keep using JS or jquery.

Thanks for looking, and help is appreciated.